# PHP HTML strip_tags all except some and remove styling from within tag

Tags: php, strip-tags

The HTML looks like this:

```
$html = 'SOME TEXT<p style="border-top: 0.0px;border-right: 0.0px;vertical-align: baseline;border-bottom: 0.0px;color: #000000;padding-bottom: 0.0px;padding-top: 0.0px;padding-left: 0.0px;margin: 0.0px;border-left: 0.0px;padding-right: 0.0px;background-color: #ffffff;">SOME TEXT';
```

I tried `strip_tags($html, '<p>');` to remove everything except for `<p>` but that preserves all the style elements of the tag.

I want the above to be replaced with just `<p>`

What's the best approach?

Thanks!

Comment: For this you need a regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution for this would be something based on [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$html = 'SOME TEXT<p style="border-top: 0.0px;border-right: 0.0px;vertical-align: baseline;border-bottom: 0.0px;color: #000000;padding-bottom: 0.0px;padding-top: 0.0px;padding-left: 0.0px;margin: 0.0px;border-left: 0.0px;padding-right: 0.0px;background-color: #ffffff;">SOME TEXT';
$html = strip_tags($html, '<p>');
$html = preg_replace('/\sstyle=["\'][A-Za-z0-9-:\s.;#]{1,}["\']/', '', $html);
```

As always, you should always be somewhat careful when trying to parse html with regex.  For instance, this would fail if for some reason the text inside the `<p />` tag contained something formatted like a css style.  (Something like `<p>If I typed style="color:red" inside the tags, it would also be removed</p>`)

The next step to make something like this better would be to actually parse the string as an XML document using the [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).  It depends on how robust a feature set you are looking to achieve.  However, this method could change your string in unexpected ways; for instance, parsing your string as a DOMDocument would cause a `</p>` tag to be added. That kind of validation may or may not be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

also some time very useful will remove style tag like below

```
`$html = '<style>li {
    list-style: none;
    background: url(/images/Articles/ordasoft_discount.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
li p{font-size:16px}
ul li {
    padding-left: 30px;}
.portfolio-container{width: 45%;}
</style> Hello word ';`
```

this will help:

```
`$html = preg_replace('/<style>[A-Za-z0-9-:\s.\/_;#\(\)\{\}%]{1,}<\/style>/', '',$html) ;`
```